# OpenGL 4.0 quickly redraw entire rendering in GL_LINE (make everything see through)

Tags: opengl

I am new to OpenGL and just need to know if there is a quick way to save the rendering/picture/view as it is, redraw it all as lines not filled in (basically make everything see-thru) and then after the user is happy, go to the saved rendering and re-display it.

Must I go back through and try to redraw everything, isn't OpenGL setup such that I can just save whatever is currently drawn/displayed, copy it, change it (redraw it all with GL_LINES instead of GL_FILL), display it, let the user do whatever they wish, and when the user is done restore it back the original saved copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how OpenGL works, since OpenGL is not a scene management library. All that OpenGL does is draw simple primitives (like points, lines or triangles) to the screen. Once it has drawn something (converted it from a bunch of triangles or lines to a bunch of pixels in the framebuffer) it completely forgets about it. So you cannot tell OpenGL to magically redraw the scene you recently drew (what is *"recently"* in this context anyway?) with another render style (polygon mode in your case).

You can of course save the current rendering (the current contents of the framebuffer) by copying it into a texture (or directly rednering it into a texture using an FBO) and then restore it by just drawing this texture to the screen. But every higher level scene management is completely your responsibility and if you want to redraw the scene with a different polygon mode, then you don't have another option than redraw the whole scene yourself.

Comment: I have a 3-D model of something in OpenGL, I can rotate the model, spin it around, etc. At some point I want to be able to hit a button and turn the entire model into a wire frame. So I do have all the primitives to create the view (what is it called, the picture? view? rendering?). I was hoping I could do something like glSaveView(tempBuffer), glRedraw(GL_LINE), glRestoreSavedView(tempBuffer). But as it looks from your answer, I am learning OpenGL today.

Comment: @BumSkeeter Exactly. You will have to redraw the whole view like before and just set do a `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` before drawing the objects. But that's really not a problem, since you need some render routine anyway, that you call each frame or each time the user moves the camera. So it just amounts to a simple per-scene or per-object property you need to check when rendering your view.

Comment: If you have the whole model, then it should be easy to just put an if statement in your code somewhere to draw the code using `GL_LINES`/`GL_LINE_LOOP` instead of `GL_POLYGONS` or whatever you are using. However, what OpenGL remembers is just the rendered version of what you drew, so there is no OpenGL function to do this.

Comment: @Xymostech Well that it the absolutely wrong approach. First of all never ever draw `GL_POLYGONS`, that's rubbish (and fortunately deprectated in newer versions). To draw something in wireframe you don't change the primitive type, because that usually won't work without changing the whole vertex order (except for the `GL_LINE_LOOP/GL_POLYGON` appraoch). You only need to change the `glPolygonMode` setting. Othwerwise your general comment is correct, of course.

Comment: @ChristianRau Wow, I never even knew that `glPolygonMode` existed. Is that something new, or have I never gone looking for that? And I don't use `GL_POLYGONS`, I just figured it would be the easiest way to explain.

Comment: I see a few `glEnable( GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH )` in the code, does this fall under don't use `GL_POLYGONS`? And thanks to both of you two.

Comment: @Xymostech It's been there all the time and is one of the most basic settings (and one of the few not removed in modern OpenGL).

Comment: @BumSkeeter `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` doesn't have anything to do with `GL_POLYGON` primitive mode. But you shouldn't use `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` for antialiasing either, but that is an entirely different question, though.